# DurandalJS: how to reposition a dialog?

Tags: durandal

I am using the following code to show a dialog when a click happens:

```
SomeViewModel.prototype.aButtonWasClicked = function() {
    var self = this;
    return dialog.show(new AnotherViewModel(self));
};
```

This creates a dialog which is bound to AnotherViewModel. However, at a certain point I inject contents in there, and the dialog needs to get resized.

The documentation says to do it like this:

```
dialog.getContext().reposition(view);
```

But... what is "`view`" and how can I retrieve it, from within `AnotherViewModel`?

Answer (score 1):

The [`reposition`](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/DialogContext/method/reposition) function expects `view` to be a `DOMElement` type. I would assume that this is the view contained in the dialog that you injected new content into. You can obtain a reference to it from the [`compositionComplete`](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/DialogContext/method/compositionComplete) function.

Without the code of your `AnotherViewModel`, it's difficult to help solve the problem. I can only make a guess. The following code is for illustrative purposes only.

---

```
function AnotherViewModel() {
}

AnotherViewModel.prototype.compositionComplete = function(view, parent, context) {
  this.view = view;
  dialog.getContext().reposition(this.view); // assumes you have a reference to `dialog`
};
```